# Is there any way to create a 2010 style site in Office 365?

Tags: 2010, office-365

Is there any way to create a 2010 version site in Office 365?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. All new sites are created with  the current version of the product. There is no way to do it in the UI and it's mentioned in their documentation. I'm trying to find a link for you.